# Building a table from two-dimensional array using ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to build a table from an array that has this scheme:

```
var items = [
    {
        name: 'xxx',
        configurations: [
            { 
                image: 'aaa.jpg'
            },
            { 
                image: 'bbb.jpg'
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'yyy',
        configurations: [
            { 
                image: 'ccc.jpg'
            },
            { 
                image: 'ddd.jpg'
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I want to to achive one single row with all images from all elements (every image is nested in one `<td>`, like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="aaa.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="bbb.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="ccc.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="ddd.jpg">
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I do it with angular? My code so far looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat-start="proposition in items">
        <img ng-src="{{::proposition.configurations[0].image}}" />
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat-end>
        <img ng-src="{{::proposition.configurations[1].image}}" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

But obviously a number of `configurations` in `proposition` is dynamic, so how can I iterate through it, keeping the same html scheme?

Comment: So, if a configuration contains multiple images, do you want these images in the same `<td>`?

Comment: @Cerbrus No, I would like every image to be in a separate `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to run two ng-repeat, one for **items** and one for **configuration**.

**Edit**

Simplest way is to flatten your array. 
So you will have a long array with tuples of `<image, name>`

You can do that with map:

That's code:

```
 $scope.items =  [
    {
        name: 'xxx',
        configurations: [
            { 
                image: 'yyy.jpg'
            },
            { 
                image: 'yyy2.jpg'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'yyy',
        configurations: [
            { 
                image: 'zzz.jpg'
            },
            { 
                image: 'zzz2.jpg'
            }
        ]
    },
];

  $scope.items = $scope.items.map(function(item){
    return item.configurations.map(function(inner){
        return { name: item.name, image: inner.image};
    })
  })

  $scope.items = $scope.items.concat.apply([], $scope.items);
```

You have a full working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNxxJO).

Comment: But how exactly should I do it to keep the same structure?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to deal with it just in a view, but I guess that I really need to modify my data in controller which is not perfect, but probably the only way to do it with angular. Apart from some mistakes like you create multiple tr elements (we can move ng-repeat to td) and the fact that it would be better to make a separate function in the controller to flatten the date (so we don't modify the original data), that gives the solution to my problem, thanks!